# Printing alphabet pyramid in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in C that gives a 13 row pyramid with the following output (notice the pattern of the letters i.e BCB):

```
            A
           BCB
          DEFED
         GHIJIHG
        KLMNONMLK
       PQRSTUTSRQP
      VWXYZABAZYXWV
     CDEFGHIJIHGFEDC
    KLMNOPQRSRQPONMLK
   TUVWXYZABCBAZYXWVUT
  DEFGHIJKLMNMLKJIHGFED
 OPQRSTUVWXYZYXWVUTSRQPO
ABCDEFGHIJKLMLKJIHGFEDCBA
```

Here is my attempt at the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void){

    char c = 'A';
    int height = 13;
    int max = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++){
        //int j = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < height - i; k++) 
            printf(" "); // print space on left
        for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++){ 
            if (j <= max / 2){ // print left side of pyramid 
                printf ("%c", c);
                c = (c - 'A' + 1) % 26 + 'A';
            }
            else{ // print right side of pyramid 
            printf ("%c", c);
            c = (c -'A' + 25) % 26 + 'A';
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        max += 2;
    }

}
```

However it gives the following incorrect output:

```
            A
           ZAZ
          YZAZY
         XYZAZYX
        WXYZAZYXW
       VWXYZAZYXWV
      UVWXYZAZYXWVU
     TUVWXYZAZYXWVUT
    STUVWXYZAZYXWVUTS
   RSTUVWXYZAZYXWVUTSR
  QRSTUVWXYZAZYXWVUTSRQ
 PQRSTUVWXYZAZYXWVUTSRQP
OPQRSTUVWXYZAZYXWVUTSRQPO
```

if I remove the the `if/else` statement which splits the pyramid in to two sides and simply have only `c = (c - 'A' + 1) % 26 + 'A';`, I get the following output:

```
            A
           BCD
          EFGHI
         JKLMNOP
        QRSTUVWXY
       ZABCDEFGHIJ
      KLMNOPQRSTUVW
     XYZABCDEFGHIJKL
    MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
   DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
  WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
 RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're forgetting to increment the actual overall character. For each line, you need to add characters until you get to the value that you should start at for the next line. Thankfully, this is pretty easy to do:

```
    ...
    max += 2;
    c = (c - 'A' + max / 2 + 1) % 26 + 'A'; // Add this line
}
```

Comment: @johnchen902 You sure? I literally copy-pasted the code to make sure it works. Are you putting it before or after `max += 2`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I put it before `max += 2`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HEIGHT 6

int main(void) {
    char* f = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char* b = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA";
    int c = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<HEIGHT; ++i)
    {
        printf("%*.*s%.*s\n", 10, i+1, f+i+c, i, b+strlen(b)-(c+2*i));
        c+=i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/d90eRD)

## Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
         A
        BCB
       DEFED
      GHIJIHG
     KLMNONMLK
    PQRSTUTSRQP
```